# Optimal way of multiple threads' referencing singleton object at the same time

Tags: java, singleton

I've been developing a web services using Java/axis2/ActiveMq 
which involves the interchange of massive message objects between system and user.

The number of logged user is equal to that of session objects(within SessionObjectSpace). For example,

```
if ( UserManager.getInstance().isLoggedIn( "userIdentifier" ) == true )
{
    SessionObjectSpace.getInstance().getUserSession( "userIdentifier" ).doSomething();
        :
        :
}
```

Accessing each user's session object is done as above and it happens a lot of
times in many threads throughout the codes. 
Since it uses singleton pattern, a single static object may have to talk to many requests (seemingly) at the same time as the count of logged users grow.

For shared objects I think I've fully protected the system by synchronization
techniques provided by Java.

Is accessing session objects that way reasonable?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your question, but if you're stuck to singleton pattern, these session objects can be designed to be immutable or only write upon a given method, then you can implement synchronization with something like a ReentrantReadWriteLock. If the method getUserSession() connects to a map that is rarely updated, it itself can be protected via a ReadWriteLock to improve the read performance.

Comment: Yeah, inside getUserSesion() is a hash map that stores SessionObject as value whose key is userIdentifier(string). I am just afraid that when the number of logged user reach some limits, the performance of web service may decrease drastically.